# Integrate Spring 4 with EJB in legacy system

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ejb

**TL;DR**: How do I autowire an EJB into a Spring `@Controller`??

---

I'm trying to add a new Spring 4 webapp into a legacy system that currently uses EJBs, and runs in Resin 4. All EJBs are `Stateless`, and `Local`, and all contain:

```
@Resource 
SessionContext ejbContext
```

EJBs are looked up via a singleton that contains the line:

```
return new InitialContext().lookup("production/entapp/default/myapplication/" + className + "/local");
```

I've got no experience of using EJBs other than via this method, so I'm not too familiar with how the lookup is performed, only that all the EJBs are found in this manner.

My question:
How do I autowire an EJB into a Spring `@Controller`??

I suspect I need to create an Interceptor of some kind, that will perform this lookup when it finds the need to autowire an EJB, but having looked through pages and pages of Google and SO, I'm none the wiser.

It's also worth mentioning that I'm trying to do all of this without any XML, using a Java `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Just slap an `@Ejb` on there instead of lookups. That should also work in your EJBs instead of lookups... Or just put a `<jee:jndi-lookup ... />` for the EJB in the application context and simply inject it.

Comment: So, say I have an `@EJB` called `UserAgentImpl` that implements `IUserAgent`, that has a `@Resource SessionContext` injected by the container, how would I use the `<jee:jndi-lookup .../>` tag in a Spring `@Configuration` class to wire up this EJB?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion. The `@EJB` annotation was already there, but I didn't have the `mappedName` property set. The lookup was always being done manually (as described). Now I've set the `mappedName` it appears to work.